# Can we get underscores in printf instead of blank spaces while writing "%15.2f" or something like that?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double B = 2006.008;
    printf("%15.2f", B);  

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   +2006.01
```

with blank spaces in the beginning

I want to replace those white spaces with underscores(_). Is there any syntax in print or any direct method to do that?

My desired output:

```
_______+2006.01
```

Comment: `iostream` is not C, and your question is also not specific to a C++ standard

Comment: You can "print to memory", then call a user-defined (by you) function that replaces every `' '` with one `'_'`

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: *Can we get underscores in `printf` instead of blank spaces while writing "%15.2f"...?*  No.

Comment: Figure out how to use `std::fill`, `std::setprecision`, `std::setw()`, etc. and use streams, not printf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments suggested you can write a function for this, but not with printf().

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::string formatNumber(double number)
{
    char buffer[15 + 1 + 2];
    sprintf(buffer, "%15.2f", number);  

    std::string s(buffer);
    std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), ' ', '_');

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    double B = 2006.008;
    auto toPrint = formatNumber(B);

    std::cout << toPrint << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (C++20), you might do:

```
std::format("{:_>15.2}", B);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qbozEo3v)

Answer (score 3):

> or any direct method to do that?

One solution is to use the [iomanip](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) manipulators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double B = 2006.008;
    printf("%15.2f\n", B);  // Original

    std::cout 
    << std::setfill('_') // The fill character
    << std::right        // right justify
    << std::setw(15)     // field width
    << std::fixed        // fixed precision
    << std::setprecision(2)  // 2 decimals
    << B;
}
```

Output:

```
        2006.01
________2006.01
```